# Representing one-to-many relationship in R with efficient memory usage

Tags: r

I have a fairly large dataset from an experiment I am running.  My experiments emits data in a csv.  However, one of the fields in the csv is additionally separated by spaces.  How can I efficiently represent this in R?

Right now I parse the csv into a data frame, and then convert the variable field into a list of smaller data frames.  Logically, this represents the data well, but it uses a ton of memory.  R only uses ~150MB to parse the csv file, but the conversion of the variable field uses 8GB, at which point my machine runs out of memory.

Comment: The variable field only needs to be a list of vectors, not a list of data frames, surely? `list(c(1,34,3),c(5,2,1,2,3),c(5,5))` etc assuming its all one type.

Answer (score 1):

I would checkout the `data.table` package. Use its `fread()` to load your data. It inherits many of the properties of `data.frame`, but handles large data better. The package is on [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html). If you're decent at `R`, the packages is not too hard to learn and handles large data better than `base` `R`.

Without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), I cannot provide any additional coding tips.